# How do I compute v.kernel maps in less than 16 hours?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, heat-map, density

I am using the GRASS GIS 6.4.2 bundled with QGIS 1.8.0, using a PostGIS dataset exported via **v.in.org.qgis** from QGIS, to create kernel density maps.

The layer has 738,288 points.

My problem is the kernel density map takes about 16 hours to compute.

Here's parameters reported by **v.kernel** as it's executing:

```
STDDEV: 1000.000000
RES: 111.419043 ROWS: 458   COLS: 447

Writing output raster map using smooth parameter=1000.000000.

Normalising factor=6482635.018778.
```

I am running this on a Windows 7 x64 laptop with 8 GB RAM and an Intel Core i7 Q720 1.6 GHz with 4 physical cores. I notice that it's not multithreaded, only using 1 core.

Is there any way to speed this up without harming the quality of the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the record, v.kernel has been improved in GRASS 7 the other day and takes (I believe) now less than 50% of the time.

Comment: Is this the same as the v.kernel improvement you put into r53982 and r53983?

Comment: Just want to confirm that r53983 of 6.4.3 converted the almost-a-day execution into 25.5 minutes!

Comment: ...which is *still* a thousand times slower than other implementations, such as the `R` code I supplied!

Comment: Could be - and the quality is the same?

Answer (score 5):

A kernel density for this size grid only takes a fraction of a second.  Evidently, the problem is that `v.kernel` is processing every one of your three quarters of a million points with too much precision and detail.

Instead, first create a grid to represent the point data, possibly using a finer resolution to reduce the discretization error in location.  (Perhaps 4580 rows by 4470 columns, for instance.)   The computation even for this much larger grid (it has 100 times as many cells) should still take only a few seconds.  Experiment first with a smaller subset of the points and a coarse grid before undertaking the full calculation.

---

#### Edit

An `R` FFT in multiple dimensions (tested only in two, though) illustrates the algorithm.  It takes roughly three seconds per million cells to convolve moderate-sized kernels with large grids.

```
filter <- function(x, kernel, ...) {
  # The kernel is centered at its middle.
  # Returns an array of the same dimensions as `x`.
  convolution <- function(x, y) {
    fft.mult <- function(x, ...) {
      z <- x
      d <- dim(z)
      for (i in length(d):1) {
        z <- apply(z, i, fft, ...)
      }
      z
    }
    reverse <- function(y) { # (Can be handy)
      if (is.null(dim(y))) rev(y) else array(rev(y), dim(y))
    }
    x.hat <- fft.mult(x)
    y.hat <- fft.mult(y)
    fft.mult(x.hat * y.hat, inverse=TRUE) / length(x)
  }
  pad <- function(x, pre, post, z=0) {
    # Pad array x in front with pre[i] and in back with post[i] values of z in dimension i.
    d <- length(dim(x))
    if (d > 1) {
      y <- apply(x, d, function(u) pad(u, pre[-d], post[-d], z))
      n <- prod(dim(y)[-d])
      y <- c(rep.int(z, pre[d] * n), y, rep.int(z, post[d] * n))
      array(y, dim(x) + pre + post)
    }
    else {
      y <- c(rep.int(z, pre), x, rep.int(z, post))
      array(y, length(y))
    }
  }
  padding <- dim(kernel)-1
  d <- nextn(dim(x) + padding, ...) # Optional argument is `factors`
  y <- pad(x, padding*0, padding + d - dim(x))
  k <- pad(kernel, padding*0, dim(y) - dim(kernel))
  z <- Re(convolution(y, k))
  e <- dim(x)
  shift <- floor(padding/2)
  z <- do.call(`[`, as.list(c(quote(z), lapply(1:length(e), function(i) 1:e[i]+shift[i]))))
  dim(z) <- dim(x) # Handles mere vectors
  z
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear what you're saying. First you say to use my 700K points on a finer grid with 100X as many cells, but then you say I should use "a smaller subset of the points and a coarse grid"? Aren't these conflicting?

Comment: In writing "experiment first" I mean that for the *final calculation* you may desire a finer grid, so that you don't lose too much resolution in the point positions, but *before waiting for that computation,* please make a trial of the complete workflow with fewer points and a coarser grid. This will enable you to streamline the procedure and benchmark its performance so at the end, when you're doing it for real on the full dataset at full resolution, you will know how long it's going to take and what to expect for output.

Comment: OK, thanks. Are you recommending perhaps a random sample of data, then slowly build up the sample size and grid size? But even then, what am I looking for? The right v.kernel parameters to produce the desired output in an acceptable amount of time? The right balance between # of points and grid size?

Comment: If all goes well, you will discover that the calculation takes essentially no time at all. You will want to experiment with grid resolution, to assure you don't lose too much precision in gridding the points. You want to make sure that in gridding the points, the data are correctly represented in raster form. You may wish to experiment with the kernel bandwidth--that's usually wise.  But don't randomly sample the data: instead, use a small window into one or more characteristic parts of your study area. When all looks good, don't go in stages: just do the final calculation.

Comment: I guess I'm still lost here. I selected a pretty small region of the map, probably about 5% of the total map area. It was not "hot" on the original heatmap, closer to being one of the weaker areas. I ran v.kernel, and it took about 1 minute. Then I increased the resolution by about tenfold in the GRASS region. Re-running v.kernel on this small area, it's going to take about 10 minutes. So I'm still not clear where you are coming from on how increasing the resolution is going to make this faster.

Comment: Correction: it's taking closer to 25 minutes to do the v.kernel on the high resolution small area.

Comment: Increasing the resolution is not intended to make it *faster*: it's to ensure you aren't losing precision when rasterizing the points. Normally, a good implementation of a density algorithm uses the FFT, which will scale almost with the number of cells in the grid (there's a logarithmic factor in there too, but it's hardly noticeable). A bad implementation will scale with the *square* of the number of cells. So you should do some timing studies over a range of resolutions with small grids to see what the scaling is. If it's quadratic, look for different software.

Comment: Concerning your comments about algorithm efficiency: I'm not sure kernel density maps are as fast as you think? I've also tried with Quantum GIS's built in heatmap feature, and it's even slower. And conceptually, this seems like an O(n^2) difficulty problem?

Comment: You are correct that it seems O(n^2), yet I am *absolutely* sure of what I wrote about the timing. My point is that you might indeed be the victim of a O(n^2) program that should be written with a O(n log(n)) algorithm. I (long ago) wrote kernel density code and timed it extensively. See http://www.directionsmag.com/features/convolution/129753 and its *sequelae* at http://www.directionsmag.com/features/convolution-part-2-of-3/129751 and http://www.directionsmag.com/features/convolution-part-3-of-3/129750 .

Comment: That is an interesting article. Seems like input-centric has advantages where you don't have a good index or when you have far more points than output grid squares, but that's beside the point, I guess, since you found great speed advantages with the FFT. Regrettably, my math education doesn't extend beyond a Mathematics BA, so this is challenging. Anyway, the comments in v.kernel's main.c (http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/browser/grass/trunk/vector/v.kernel/main.c) indicate use of a "moving kernel", so I wonder if GRASS uses the output-centric method?

Comment: Yup, I *think* line 403 is where it traverses the output grid and then does spatial queries to see who is nearby--if I'm reading correctly.

Comment: This code seems designed for some kind of "net" (network?) based computation. That's going to make it ridiculously slow for regular grids. As a test, I just used the FFT distributed with `R` to tabulate 750,000 points onto a 1200 by 700 grid (measured elapsed time for that: 0 seconds), build a Gaussian kernel (0.12 seconds), and compute the density map (3.93 seconds). This is a *slow* implementation: it would go much faster on a native array-based platform like MatLab or (I suspect) Python.

Comment: Do you know of any products that use this faster algorithm?

Comment: I *suspect* ArcGIS (with Spatial Analyst) now does so. Those I am sure of--because I have used them for this purpose and their algorithms are clearly documented--are *Mathematica*, Idrisi, `R`, and Manifold. I'm confident Python has FFT libraries available, but I haven't researched them.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking at R mainly, and looks like I might have to mostly spin my own algorithm. I'll keep investigating.

Comment: I added some code to get you going.