# Spatial join to kernel density / kernel density with polygon/point output in Arc

Tags: arcgis-desktop, density, spatial-join

I'm looking for a way to join polygons to a density function for some other feature of interest.

Current workflow

- make density raster from feature set of interest, using point/line/kernel density
- sum raster inside output geometry (for polygons) or just sample it (for points)

This seems inefficient as I have to calculate a density raster for many points I won't even use.  Is there a tool that does the same thing but without the raster?  This would be like a kernel-density-aware spatial join, or a kernel density function that outputs to a preexisting geometry rather than to a raster.

Comment: Because most kernel density rasters are computed using a fast Fourier Transform, and because this is *tremendously* faster than a direct calculation (even though it requires computing an entire rectangular grid of values), it's likely your imagined approach would be much *less* efficient in most applications.  For a recent discussion of these issues, please see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41058/how-do-i-compute-v-kernel-maps-in-less-than-16-hours.

Comment: With no Answers offered in over a year, and some useful advice having already been provided as a Comment, would you be able to either write up an Answer, or edit your Question to revise it in line with your learnings, please?

Comment: @PolyGeo The short answer was no: I didn't find a tool to do this. I did find the isectpolyraster tool in GME (geospatial modelling environment) worked better for summing the raster inside polygons than the tools in ArcGIS - which don't allow overlapping polygons. But that's a different question.